# How to fix VS2022 17.4.3 Bug "The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET 7.0."?

Tags: visual-studio-2022, .net-7.0, .net-sdk

I've been trying to begin development with .Net 7.0 in Visual Studio 17.4.3 (the latest version) and the option .NET 7.0 is not in the framework selection in the IDE.
I've installed the .NET 7.0.101 SDK and verified it from the command line.

> > C:\WINDOWS\system32>dotnet --info .NET SDK:  Version:   7.0.101  Commit:    bb24aafa11
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.19045
> OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.101\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 6.0.5   Commit:  70ae3df4a6
>
> .NET SDKs installed:
> 3.1.426 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.203 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.214 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.401 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.403 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 5.0.415 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 6.0.202 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 6.0.404 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
> 7.0.101 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.28 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.28 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.32 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.12 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 7.0.1 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 2.1.28 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.30 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 3.1.15 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 3.1.21 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.32 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.10 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 5.0.13 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
> 6.0.12 [D:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 7.0.1 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.15 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.19 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.21 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.32 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.6 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.9 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.10 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.12 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.13 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 5.0.17 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.4 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.5 [C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 6.0.12 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
> Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 7.0.1 [D:\Program
> Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>
> To install additional .NET runtimes or SDKs:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

I've verified that .NET 7.0 is checked in the VS installer as well.
I've reinstalled VS2022 completely a couple of times over the last few days attempting to resolve the issue, but alas, cannot find one.
Still stuck with .NET 6.0 and cannot find a solution to this anywhere and have tried all the recommendations on Microsoft's website to the best of my ability.

I believe this may be due to VS2022 being installed on Drive D:\ and it cannot find this framework (though ALL other frameworks display correctly!) and MS introduced a path bug, but I have no idea where to look or where to start (and don't wish to destroy my configurations for all my other, older projects).

Any ideas on how to workaround this bug?

Comment: Do you create a new project in new solution?

Comment: Yes, it let's me create a new .NET 7.0 project, but I can't compile it without an error. The project configuration dropdown won't show .net 7.0 in the list, and it ignores the setting in the csproj file.

Comment: It's a path problem, for sure, but not sure where to tell VS2022 to look in the d:\program files\dotnet\sdk\  instead of c:\program files\dotnet\sdk

Comment: I verified this by simply copying all the sdk folders over to the c: drive and I can see it in the dropdown. Now I'd like a permanent solution to this issue

Comment: There's a list of checks in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1045), check all of them.

Comment: I was there already. Like I said, the problem is that VS is not looking in both paths for the SDK. If VS is installed on the D:\ drive, it still looks to the C:\ drive for the SDKs. The VS installer installs the sdks on the same drive as VS.  VS, internally, looks at the default C:\ drive (except when creating a new project). The solution is to manually copy the files over.

Comment: When I read this post, I was reminded of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74365441/sdk-resolver-failure-net-7-net-6) which happened when they went they pushed .NET 7 out for general availability.  Worth a shot to check, but I don't _think_ that is your issue here.